# Error when printing string

Tags: php

when i print a string with php it is printin the string like this `�C�a�r� �B�u�y�i�n�g�`

how to remove this `�` ?

when i am using like this in html is script is working fine

```
{category: "Auto", measure: 6600},

{category: "Best Car", measure: 22200},

{category: "Car Auction", measure: 5400},

{category: "Car Audio", measure: 60500},

{category: "Car Battery", measure: 6600},
```

but when i am trying to print this with PHP like this

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?>    
        {category: "<?php echo $row['ad_group']; ?>", measure: <?php echo $row['volume']; ?>},
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Check the file encoding, try UTF-8.

Comment: how can i convert to utf

Comment: But the actual file that has the PHP code has an encoding.  What text editor are you using?  Usually you can set the file encoding in one of the menus at the top (File or Edit).

Comment: Open the PHP file in notepad++ and select the Encoding menu option at the top.  Select UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Is it specific to the string "Car Buying", or is it everywhere? If just that one place, are there spaces between the letters? I'll bet an editor put Latin-1/Windows-1252 xA0 bytes in for non-breaking spaces, rather than UTF-8 non-breaking spaces (or better yet, HTML `&nbsp;` entity).

Comment: there are so spaces i read from db and printed it source code is showing like this {category: "Car Buying", measure: Car Buying},{category: "Car Insurance", measure: Car Insurance},{category: "Keywords like: Car Finder", measure: Keywords like: Car Finder}, bt when i mouse over the chart it is showing with soe ugly chars

Comment: That's probably a UTF-16 string being output in something that's not unicode, e.g. iso8859

Comment: @MarcB how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

**`FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`**

**`var_dump(filter_var($your_string_variable,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));`**

`{category: "<?php echo 'Category'; var_dump(filter_var($row['ad_group'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
?>", measure: <?php var_dump(filter_var($row['volume'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)); ?>},`